# Devise Omniauth facebook redirect flash message error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth-facebook

I created a rails app with Devise and omniauth to have the fb signup. 
Everything is working but when I had the redirect to the last page after sign up I have the error on the flash message for the user coming from fb.

here is my application_controller

```
def set_redirect_path
  @redirect_path = request.path
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if params[:redirect_to].present?
    store_location_for(resource, params[:redirect_to])
  elsif request.referer == new_session_url(:user)
    super
  else
    request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
  end
end
```

and here the omniauth_callbacks_controller

```
def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])    

    if @user.persisted?
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
        session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
end

def failure
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

the flash message I get after the sign up and redirect from facebook is the already_authenticated error one saying "You are already signed in."

Does anyone knows how can I solve this issue

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to change after_sign_in_path_for method. For example in ApplicationController:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    super resource
end
```